# Mergesort algo not working

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a mergesort algorithm which is not working properly. Merge Sort works as follows:

i. Divide the unsorted list into n sublists, each containing 1 element (a list of 1 element
is considered sorted).

ii. Repeatedly merge sublists to produce newly sorted sublists until there is only 1 sublist remaining. This will be the sorted list. The implementation is provided below.

Initially, this method is called recursively till there will be only one element.

```
public void mergeSort(int low, int high) {

    if (low >= high) {
        return;
    }

    int middle = (low + high) / 2;

    // recursion for the merge
    mergeSort(low, middle);
    mergeSort(middle + 1, high);

    merge(low, middle, high);
}
```

This is the merge method provided.

```
private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

    int i = low, j = middle;
    int index = low;

    for (int k = 0; k <= high; k++) {
        tempArray[k] = nums[k];
    }

    /*
      Copy the smallest values from either the left
      or the right side back to the original array
     */
    while ((i <= middle) && (j <= high)) {
        if (tempArray[i] <= tempArray[j]) {
            nums[index++] = tempArray[i++];
        } else {
            nums[index++] = tempArray[j++];
        }
    }

    // fill the left side of the array
    while (i < middle) {
        nums[index++] = tempArray[i++];
    }

    // fill the right side of the array
    while (j < high) {
        nums[index++] = tempArray[j++];
    }
  }
```

What is the issue here?

The input is `int[] arr = {12, 3, 4, 56, -7, 1};` and the output is `12 12 12 12 56 56`

Comment: Please add output with your code. It would be difficult to get to the root of the issue otherwise.

Comment: The output `12 12 12 12 56 56`, updated the question

Comment: @devsaw I upadted the qurestion

Comment: You can find out the issue by debugging your program. Start with `mergesort(0,5)`. Print out the whole array in `merge` function.

Comment: @devsaw I debugged and updated the program. Please, have a look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the merge function and it starts to work now. Especially, the `j` needs to be initialized after the middle term `j = middle+1`

```
 private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

    int i = low, j = middle+1;
    int index = low;

    for (int k = 0; k <= high; k++) {
        tempArray[k] = nums[k];
    }

    /*
      Copy the smallest values from either the left
      or the right side back to the original array
     */
    while ((i <= middle) && (j <= high)) {
        if (tempArray[i] <= tempArray[j]) {
            nums[index++] = tempArray[i++];
        } else {
            nums[index++] = tempArray[j++];
        }
    }

    // fill the left side of the array
    while (i <= middle) {
        nums[index++] = tempArray[i++];
    }

    // fill the right side of the array
    while (j <= high) {
        nums[index++] = tempArray[j++];
    }
}
```